# JQuery autocomplete: trigger <g:select onChange>

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, grails, selection

As we all know, `javax.swing.JComboBox` is a dropdown selection having `E` elements in it. When setting `.setEditable(true)`, we now can make that `JComboBox` also a `JTextField` for other `E` element.

After searching with `Google` on this, it returned to us a suggestion of using by *JQuery* about *autocomplete* presented [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox). Autocomplete is working on the selection but here's the problem, we need to **trigger the `onChange` attribute that contains the `${remoteFunction}` to render a particular template on the `update` attribute of the said `${remoteFunction}`.**

```
<g:select  
  id="itemSelectId"
  onChange="${remoteFunction(
    controller:'item', action:'itemSelect',
    update:[success:'updateItemId'],
    params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)'"/>
<div id="updateItemId></div>
```

And on the `<script>` provided on the link we just change `#combobox` to `#itemSelectId`.

Comment: How can we trigger the `${remoteFunction}` inside the `change` attribute of the said jquery-ui, [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox).

Comment: maybe this will help: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we would prefer a combobox or `select` so that no other `E` are considered in the list.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/index.html

Comment: @Chronial, can you suggest that the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/index.html), that library might offer the features you are looking for.